# I've created an array on javascript and it does not display all the contents

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var joelsarray = [1 , 2 , "joel" , "carissa" , true];
 
for(i=0;i<joelsarray.length;i++) {
 
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="The elements of my array are " + 
    joelsarray[i] + "</br>";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="red()">Click Me!!</button>
     <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p id="demo">Hello World.Hello World.</p>
```

here is the code. It displays "the elements of my array are true" on the browser.
when i use the document.write method it works..but the document.getElementByid doesn't work need help im a newbie thanks!

Comment: Your loop is overwriting the previous contents of the HTML element. So you'll only have the last contents. Simple solution: use `+=` instead of `=`. Although not most efficient.

Comment: Because you overwrite the innerHTML on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: It is because `innerHTML` REPLACES the contents of the element. You are only seeing the last item in the array

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over all the items in the array with a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < joelsarray.length; i++) {
```

Everytime you loop, the variable `i` will be incremented: from 0 to 1 to 2..etc.

You can access the values in the array by index using the `i` from the iteration: `joelsarray[i]`. So `joelsarray[2]` would give you `joel`.

Before any looping has been done, you could assign the string using `=` to the element using:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The elements of my array are <br>";
```

When the looping starts, you want to append using `+=` the values to the string you already have added. If you would set the data during the looping using `=` , you would overwrite the data constantly after every loop.

You get this result "the elements of my array are true", because `true` is the last element in the array and would get written as last losing all the previous values.

You could add `+=` to add the inner html

```js
var joelsarray = [1, 2, "joel", "carissa", true];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The elements of my array are <br>";
for (var i = 0; i < joelsarray.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += joelsarray[i] + "</br>";
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p id="demo">Hello World.Hello World.</p>
```

Comment: Hey if you wouldn't mind , could you please elaborate a bit on what you just said...It literally went over my head.Thanks!

Comment: I mean why using the += sign help??

Comment: @user9295496 I have added an explanation to my answer. If you use the equals sign `=` to assign data, which you will do in every loop. Resulting in overwriting the data in every time you loop. Using `+=`, you append the data. [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) might help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I couldn't find the explanation before i could only see a code snippet...This has helped me so much..thanks a ton!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `join` to concatenate the string `</br>`

That `for-loop` is assigning the last value.

```js
var joelsarray = [1, 2, "joel", "carissa", true];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The elements of my array are <br>" + joelsarray.join('</br>');
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="red()">Click Me!!</button>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p id="demo">Hello World.Hello World.</p>
```